# Can/how I switch administrator access from using ssh to password in azure portal?

Tags: azure, authentication

I have test linux server created in Azure, is it possible to change the administrator access method from SSH to user/pwd or verse vice? I just started learning Azure and surely it would be better if this could be done through portal.

Can anyone help me with some instruction (ideally with screenshots)?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. In the VM, you can reset the password with a username and password instead of the SSH public key. But it also needs to SSH to the VM, just use the username and password.

A screenshot for you to take a look:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Charles.